# Trouble using jquery ui resizeable, draggable and nicEdit

Tags: jquery-ui, nicedit

I would like to create some  resizeable and draggable div tags contain textarea tags with jQueryUI.And I also want to use nicEdit to format text inside these textarea tags.But i can't combine them,maybe.I can't edit text if i use $(element).resizeable().draggable().Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Trouble using  jquery ui resizeable, draggable and nicEdit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="nicEdit/nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var btnlist=['fontSize','fontFamily',
                'bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough',
                'left','center','right','justify',
                'ol','ul','hr',
                'indent','outdent',
                'forecolor','bgcolor',
                'subscript','superscript','removeformat'];

var myNicEditor = new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'nicEdit/nicEditorIcons.gif',buttonList     :btnlist });
myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicEdit');  
function ID()
{
var id="id";
var random_number=Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
id+=random_number;
return id;
}

$('#a').click(function(){
  var id=ID();
  $('#content').append('<div class="d" style="width: 100px;height:100px;"><textarea        style="width:100%;height: 100%" id='+id+'></textarea></div>');
myNicEditor.addInstance(id);
jQuery('.d').draggable().resizable();//If i remove this line,it work ok.
});

}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button id="a">Add</button>
<div id="myNicEdit" style="width: 200px;" ></div>
<br />
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Can anyone give some solutions for me!Thank a lot!

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'handle' option when you apply draggable, so that it doesn't highjack the onmousedown event on all the child elements.